Override symbols in non-dynamic sections of dynamically linked executable
Is it possible to override symbols in the non-dynamic segments of dynamically linked executable? (For example: the .text and .(ro)data segments of an ELF executable on Linux.)
I know that it is possible to override references in the dynamic section using LD_PRELOAD.
An answer at What is the difference between LD_PRELOAD_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH? claims that LD_PRELOAD also allows overriding statically linked functions, but I'm not sure how. The man page says

LD_PRELOAD A list of additional, user-specified, ELF shared objects to be loaded before all others. This feature can be used to selectively override functions in other shared objects.

so unless everything in a dynamically linked executable is a shared object (only some are included and some are referenced?) this sounds like what I want isn't possible using LD_PRELOAD, but maybe still using some other tool?

Your terminology suggests some haziness about the anatomy of an ELF program but I believe you are asking: If the definition of symbol foo
is statically linked into a program, can that definition by dynamically overridden with an alternative definition
of foo provided by a shared library pre-loaded at runtime?
In that case the answer is No.
You'll see why if you know how some
parts of an ELF program actually enable the dynamic linker, at runtime, to bind symbols
it can see in the program to definitions that it finds in shared libraries (whether or not such a binding
is overriding any prior or alternative one), and if you also know
how symbols that have statically linked definitions in the program may or may not be
visible to the dynamic linker to do anything with.
When I talk about symbols in an ELF file here, I always exclude local symbols (a.k.a symbols with
internal linkage) such as are created by the C storage-class specifier static. They are not
visible either to the static linker or the dynamic linker. When I say that a symbol is statically linked
into the program, I mean that the static linker physically merges its definition into a code or data section of the
program executable.
Gist
By default, the static linker does not enter any symbol in the dynamic symbol table of a program
that is statically defined in the program. It is impossible for the dynamic linker to bind such
a symbol to another definition from a shared library, whether pre-loaded or loaded in the normal course
of events, because the dynamic linker does not see any such symbol. The static linker
can be expressly directed to add symbols that are statically defined in the program to its
dynamic symbol table, but they appear there as defined and the dynamic linker cannot be coerced to
redefine a defined symbol that it sees there.
The dynamic symbol table and dynamic section of a program
A symbol referenced by an ELF program that is visible to the dynamic linker is a dynamic symbol.
A dynamic symbol is exposed to the dynamic linker in the dynamic symbol table (.dynsym section) of
the program. The dynamic symbols are the only ones that the dynamic linker
can bind to definitions provided by shared libraries because they are the only symbols seen by
the dynamic linker.
By default all the symbols in a the dynamic symbol table of a program will be undefined symbols.
That's because the dynamic symbol table of a program is put there by the static linker at buildtime
and its default purpose is to inform the dynamic linker, at runtime, of the symbols which it must bind to
definitions it finds in the shared libraries it loads at the program's request. So such symbols
are undefined in the program: they are defined in the shared libraries it needs to load. If any symbols appear
in the dynamic symbol table as defined, that means they are defined in the program and the dynamic linker
of course will not bother trying to find other definitions for them in the shared libraries.
All symbols that are referenced in the program executable are referenced in object files that
are statically linked into it (either object files explicitly input in the static linker's commandline
or object files selected for extraction from static libraries input in the commandline).
The undefined symbols that are entered into the program's dynamic symbol table by default
are the ones for which the static linker has found references in statically linked object files and:

are not defined in any of the input object files.

are defined by the shared libraries that are input in the static linker's commandline.


By definition, those shared libraries wont't (and can't) be statically linked into the program, hence these
symbols cannot be defined in the program. Instead, the static linker
just puts into the program the fact that it needs those shared libraries, for the information of the dynamic linker
at runtime. It puts a dynamic section into the program (.dynamic section) and in that section it writes (among other things)
a list of the shared libraries that the dynamic linker will need to load to resolve all the undefined symbols
that it has written into the program's dynamic symbol table.
An runtime, the dynamic linker reads the program's dynamic symbol table (.dynsym) and learns what undefined dynamic
symbols it has to resolve using shared libraries. It reads the program's dynamic section (.dynamic) and learns what
shared libraries it must find and load to resolve those symbols. It goes to work, using an algorithmically
defined sequence of directories in which to search for shared libraries. The work is recursive,
because each shared library that it loads has its own dynamic symbol table, listing the symbols that are
defined in it, as well as the ones that it references but does not define; and it has its own dynamic section
that lists the shared libraries it needs to resolve its undefined symbols. If the work finishes with
all the recursively needed shared libraries found and all of the recursively discovered undefined references
resolved by the recursively discovered definitions, then the program gets to start successfully.
The global symbol table of a program
The dynamic symbol table of a program is distinct from its global symbol table (.symtab section). The global
symbol table lists all global symbols in the program that were referenced in the object files statically
linked into the program. By default all of these symbols will appear as defined, because if any symbol is
referenced in the program and is undefined in the program, then either:-
a) a definition was found by the static linker in some shared library, or
b) no definition was found by the static linker at all.
In case a) the symbol will be listed in the dynamic symbol table (as undefined) and not listed in
the global symbol table. In case b) the static linker by default will fail the linkage with an
unresolved reference error, so the program will not even exist.
But a statically linked definition with its symbol in the global symbol table is invisible to the dynamic linker. The
global symbol table can be stripped out (man strip)
with no effect on execution of the program. Its existence only supports tools that investigate or manipulate ELF files.
But that's all by default. What about coercion?
That's a dead end too.
You can coerce the static linker to link a program that contains unresolved symbol references (linker option -z=undefs). That is
obviously of no help because you are interested in dynamically overriding the statically linked definition of a defined symbol.
You can also coerce the static linker to add all, or a selection, of the symbols it puts in global symbol table of
a program into the dynamic symbol table as well: linker option --export-dynamic to add them all (the GCC linkage option
-rdynamic enables that one), linker option --export-dynamic-symbol=sym to
add one, linker option --export-dynamic-symbol-list=file to export a selection. But that doesn't help either because
these statically defined symbols will be added to the dynamic symbol table as defined. The usefulness of
that is that it enables shared libraries that are loaded by the program to contain undefined references to symbols
that the dynamic linker will resolve to definitions in the program. It is of no use for dynamically overriding such
a definition, because the dynamic linker will not seek to resolve a symbol that is already defined.
A static linker could be written that classifies a symbol in the dynamic symbol table with a new type, say,
defined-as-last-resort, meaning the the dynamic linker should bind it to the definition statically linked into the file
that exports it failing a definition in any (other) shared library. Perverse, but it would do the trick. But if such a static linker has been written, it's not the GNU/linux linker.
A worked illustration
$ cat main.c
void statically_linked(void);
void dynamically_linked(void);

int main(void)
{
    statically_linked();
    dynamically_linked();
    return 0;
}

$ cat static.c 
#include <stdio.h>

void statically_linked(void)
{
    puts(__FUNCTION__);
}

$ cat dynamic.c 
#include <stdio.h>

void dynamically_linked(void)
{
    puts(__FUNCTION__);
}

$ cat preload_static.c
#include <stdio.h>

void statically_linked(void)
{
    printf("%s: pre-loaded\n",__FUNCTION__);
}

$ gcc -shared -o libdynamic.so dynamic.c
$ gcc -shared -o libpreload_static.so preload_static.c

$ gcc -o prog main.c static.c -L. -ldynamic

$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./ ./prog
statically_linked
dynamically_linked

$ readelf --syms --wide prog | egrep \(.symtab\|.dynsym\|ally_linked\)
Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 8 entries:
     5: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND dynamically_linked
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 40 entries:
    32: 0000000000001182    26 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   16 statically_linked
    33: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND dynamically_linked
    

The dynamic section of prog contains:
$ readelf --dynamic --wide ./prog | grep NEEDED
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdynamic.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 

The dynamic linker will find libc.so.6 by default search. It will have to be told where to
look for libdynamic.so, which we did with LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./. Alternatively we could
have got the static linker to add this information to the dynamic section:
$ gcc -o prog main.c static.c -L. -ldynamic -Wl,-rpath=$(pwd)

$ readelf --dynamic --wide ./prog | egrep \(NEEDED\|RUNPATH\)
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdynamic.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [/home/imk/develop/so/scrap]
 
$ unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$ ./prog
statically_linked
dynamically_linked

statically_linked appears as defined in the global symbol table only. dynamically_linked
appears as undefined (UND) in both the global symbol table and the dynamic symbol table.
dynamically_linked is the only symbol that is seen by the dynamic linker, so it is
the only one for which the dynamic linker could be induced to seek a definition in a some shared library pre-loaded before libdynamic.so, where
it will otherwise find the same definition discovered by the static linker.
Let's rebuild prog this time adding statically_linked to the dynamic symbol table:
$ gcc -o prog main.c static.c -rdynamic -L. -ldynamic -Wl,-rpath=$(pwd)
$ readelf --syms --wide prog | egrep \(.symtab\|.dynsym\|ally_linked\)
Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 17 entries:
     5: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND dynamically_linked
    16: 0000000000001182    26 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   16 statically_linked
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 40 entries:
    34: 0000000000001182    26 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   16 statically_linked
    35: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND dynamically_linked
        

There it is - it's defined (in section 16, which is .text). Let's try to override the
statically linked definition by pre-loading libpreload_static.so. That should result
in the program outputing statically_linked: preloaded instead of statically_linked
$ LD_PRELOAD=./libpreload_static.so ./prog
statically_linked
dynamically_linked

But it doesn't. statically_linked is defined in the dynamic symbol table. The
dynamic linker sees nothing to be done.
If that's convincing, stop. But I anticipate...
What about the cited example where `LD_PRELOAD` supposedly trumps a statically linked definition?
This is the example presented by @hackerb9 in this answer, which
purportedly showed that:

LD_PRELOAD can replace functions statically linked into a binary.

But the answer does not actually demonstrate that. It just implies that @hackerb9 observed it to
be so after doing what is described in the example.
The implied claim is that:

The stock bash shell is built with libreadline.a linked in furnishing statically linked definitions of the readline
functions called by bash. (That much is true).

@hackerb9 built a version of the shared library libreadline.so in which some of those functions were modified.

When @hackerb9 LD_PRELOAD-ed the modified libreadline.so for running bash, the modified readline functions
were called, overriding their statically linked definitions.


Since that defies first principles, our only resort is to test it by reproduction. Sadly that's
a long addendum, but...
Let's do it!
For this, my modified readline shared library will be built from the source:
$ cat badrl.c 
#include <stddef.h>
#include <assert.h>

char * readline (const char *prompt) {
    assert(0);
    return NULL;
}

#ifdef PROGRAM
int main(void)
{
    (void)readline(NULL);
    return 0;
}
#endif

A program that calls my readline function is:
$ gcc -o prog -DPROGRAM badrl.c

and it aborts:
$ ./prog
prog: badrl.c:5: readline: Assertion `0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

Build my shared readline library, called libbadrl.so:
$ gcc -shared -o libbadrl.so badrl.c

My installed bash version is 5.2.21. I'll build that one locally from source to tinker with it:
$ wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-5.2.21.tar.gz
...[all good]...
$ tar -xzf bash-5.2.21.tar.gz 
$ cd bash-5.2.21/
$ ./configure
...[all good]...

I'll grep the gcc linkage line for bash out of the make output for later use:
$ make 2>&1 | grep 'gcc .*-o bash .*'
gcc -L./builtins -L./lib/readline -L./lib/readline -L./lib/glob -L./lib/tilde -L./lib/malloc -L./lib/sh  -rdynamic -g -O2   -o bash shell.o eval.o y.tab.o general.o make_cmd.o print_cmd.o  dispose_cmd.o execute_cmd.o variables.o copy_cmd.o error.o expr.o flags.o jobs.o subst.o hashcmd.o hashlib.o mailcheck.o trap.o input.o unwind_prot.o pathexp.o sig.o test.o version.o alias.o array.o arrayfunc.o assoc.o braces.o bracecomp.o bashhist.o bashline.o  list.o stringlib.o locale.o findcmd.o redir.o pcomplete.o pcomplib.o syntax.o xmalloc.o  -lbuiltins -lglob -lsh -lreadline -lhistory -ltermcap -ltilde -lmalloc    -ldl

Notice - scroll right - that the gcc linkage options include -rdynamic. That enables --export-dynamic for the linker and means that all
the symbols in the global symbol table will be added to the dynamic symbol table. We've already observed that makes no difference.
I've got a ./bash from that make. Let's check the symbol tables for readline:
$ readelf -Ws ./bash | egrep \(.symtab\|.dynsym\|FUNC.*readline$\)
Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 2603 entries:
   932: 00000000000d1c90   153 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   16 readline
  1323: 0000000000099510  2039 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   16 initialize_readline
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 3995 entries:
  1846: 0000000000099510  2039 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   16 initialize_readline
  2260: 00000000000d1c90   153 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   16 readline
  

Yes, it's defined and has been statically linked per the .symtab, and -rdynamic has put it into .dynsym as well.
Check my bash runs, and its read command works:
$ ./bash
$ read
Hello World!
$ echo $REPLY
Hello World!
$ exit
exit

Good. Now I'll compile my aborting badrl.c into a object file (PROGRAM not defined):
$ gcc -c -o badrl.o ../badrl.c

And I'll repeat the gcc linkage command for bash with the following tweaks:

Change the name of the output program from bash to badrlbash.
Input badrl.o to the linkage, so that my aborting readline function is statically linked.
Change the linkage of the readline library from -lreadline to -Wl,--push-state,-Bdynamic,-lreadline,--pop-state. The
effect of that is to link the shared library version of libreadline instead of linking it statically, eliminating any
multiple definition error for readline caused by statically linking definitions from both badrl.o and ./lib/readline/libreadline.a(readline.o),
(the one output by make, pulled into the linkage by other symbols).
The shared libreadline will resolve all the undefined libreadline symbols in the program other than the readline function from badrl.o
already statically linked.
Remove -L./lib/readline from the linkage command so that the linker won't look there for the readline library
and will instead just search in my system default library directories.

That gives:
$ gcc -L./builtins -L./lib/glob -L./lib/tilde -L./lib/malloc -L./lib/sh  -rdynamic -g -O2   -o badrlbash badrl.o shell.o eval.o y.tab.o general.o make_cmd.o print_cmd.o  dispose_cmd.o execute_cmd.o variables.o copy_cmd.o error.o expr.o flags.o jobs.o subst.o hashcmd.o hashlib.o mailcheck.o trap.o input.o unwind_prot.o pathexp.o sig.o test.o version.o alias.o array.o arrayfunc.o assoc.o braces.o bracecomp.o bashhist.o bashline.o  list.o stringlib.o locale.o findcmd.o redir.o pcomplete.o pcomplib.o syntax.o xmalloc.o  -lbuiltins -lglob -lsh -Wl,--push-state,-Bdynamic,-lreadline,--pop-state -lhistory -ltermcap -ltilde -lmalloc    -ldl
/usr/bin/ld: ./lib/sh/libsh.a(tmpfile.o): in function `sh_mktmpname':
/home/imk/develop/so/scrap/bash-5.2.21/lib/sh/tmpfile.c:160:(.text+0x18f): warning: the use of `mktemp' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp' or `mkdtemp'

And I've got:
$ ./badrlbash 
badrlbash: ../badrl.c:5: readline: Assertion `0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

Now if @hackerb9 is right, then I can fix this broken bash by overriding the statically linked definition of readline by pre-loading the system libreadline.so,
which is:
$ find /usr/lib -name libreadline.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so

Here goes:
$ LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so ./badrlbash 
badrlbash: ../badrl.c:5: readline: Assertion `0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

But it makes no difference.
Likewise, if @hackerb9 is right, then by pre-loading my libbadrl.so I can cause an abort in the stock bash 5.2.21 I built first.
$ LD_PRELOAD=../libbadrl.so ./bash
$ read
Hello World!
$ echo $REPLY
Hello World!
$ exit
exit

But that doesn't happen either.

Thanks for this great answer and amazing level of detail (I'll take some days to unpack everything and learn some things I didn't even ask for). Spot on about my hazyness and follow up questions. I now have the original stackoverflow answer as well as one answer here (also very high quality!) on one side (it's possible somehow) and the man page, you, and the continued absence of a reproducible example on the other, so I'll accept your answer until a counterexample appears.


Is it possible to override symbols in the non-dynamic segments of dynamically linked executable?

A typical ELF binary has two separate symbol tables: the dynamic one (.dynsym and .dynstr) and the static one (.symtab and .strtab). You can examine each table separately by using nm a.out and nm -D a.out.
The static symbol table is usually retained only for debugging; nothing looks into it at runtime (though "self-aware" binaries may examine symbols there in order to e.g. print crash stack trace).
This table can be completely removed (using strip) and the binary should still run fine.
Since processing of the LD_PRELOAD and dynamic symbol resolution are performed by the dynamic linker, and since the dynamic linker never looks at the static symbol table, it follows that the only symbols which can be interposed are the dynamic ones.

An answer at ... claims that LD_PRELOAD also allows overriding statically linked functions.

You are possibly mixing two separate uses of "static" together here.
A function is statically linked into a.out when it comes from foo.o or libfoo.a -- i.e. the code of the function is present in the .text section of a.out.
That has nothing to do with "static linkage" (as in static int foo() { ... }).
Functions with both static and global linkage can be statically linked into a.out, but only functions with global linkage will appear in the dynamic symbol table (when using -rdynamic while linking a.out), and only functions which appear in the dynamic symbol table can be interposed using LD_PRELOAD.
Even for functions which do appear in the dynamic symbol table of the a.out, interposing may not work (I couldn't get it to work on Fedora 40). You may need to build the main executable with -fPIC, and possibly some more flags in recent GCC versions (I am pretty sure this used to work in the past).

Apologies if I used imprecise terminology and thanks for your insightful answer. Using your terminology, my question was indeed "is it possible to interpose functions that are statically linked into the executable?". And if I understood you correctly, the answer is: Yes, but only if (1) the function has external (you call it global) linkage (2) you make sure  the function is in the dynamic symbol table instead of the static symbol table, via -rdynamic(3) some other, unclear, conditions are satisfied that depend on operating system and compiler version.

that all makes sense to me, but I'm still confused about the man page then. Would you have a guess what they meant by "shared object" in "This feature can be used to selectively override functions in other shared objects." I understood it to mean shared object as in .so file

I have up-voted your answer because it's high quality in every regard, but now new answer appeared and claims it's fundamentally not possible to do this. If you ever find a way to achieve this I'd be very interested to see it

@Bananach The other answer claims that this is fundamentally impossible without a proof, and I believe that not only is it possible, but it's how things used to work. Note that I wasn't able to make this work on Fedora 40 either. I would have to "dust off" RedHat 7.2 to confirm whether my memory is faulty. Even my memory is wrong, that still wouldn't prove that it's fundamentally impossible.

Yes, from my perspective, there are two high quality answers by people that are much more knowledgeable than me. Neither has 100% proof, but the other answer did go through a lot of effort of trying to make it work, and it didn't. I'd be excited to be convinced otherwise.
